# JavaScript in method

Tags: javascript, socket.io

The NodeBB discussion forum https://github.com/designcreateplay/NodeBB uses an `in` method on an io.sockets object that doesn't seem to be the same as the JavaScript `in` method here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in, yet I don't see an `in` method in the socket.io docs.

What is the `in` method doing in the code below?

The ThreadTools.lock method below calls a method `websockets.in`, which, as you see here just `returns io.sockets.in(room)`. I'm

```
websockets.in = function(room) {
        return io.sockets.in(room);
    };
```

ThreadTools.lock

```
ThreadTools.lock = function(tid, socket) {
    topics.setTopicField(tid, 'locked', 1);

    if (socket) {
        websockets.in('topic_' + tid).emit('event:topic_locked', {
            tid: tid,
            status: 'ok'
        });

        if (socket) {
            socket.emit('api:topic.lock', {
                status: 'ok',
                tid: tid
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms#emitting-to-a-room) says

> There are two ways for emitting to a room: either using `socket.broadcast.to('room')` or `io.sockets.in('room')`.

Answer (score 2):

Hey @BrainLikeADullPencil!

We use `.in()` to send messages to users in a specific "room". For `ThreadTools.lock`, it is sending the `event:topic.locked` message to all users in that topic's room (users automatically join a topic room when they browse into a topic).

On the client side, we listen for that message and lock the topic in the DOM (plus various other small changes)